# element.parentNode returns null while traversing through the DOM using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to traverse through the elements starting from Log in button up parent from parent up till I find an element with id, or I arrive to the top of the DOM.
https://profile.w3schools.com/signup?redirect_url=https://billing.w3schools.com/courses/html-video-course
I use the following code to create a CSS selector:

```js
function getCssSelector(element) {
  if (!(element instanceof Element)) {
    console.log("Element is not an Element: " + element)
    return;
  }
  var path = [];
  while (element.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    var selector = element.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (element.id) {
      selector += '#' + element.id;
      path.unshift(selector);
      break;
    } else {
      var previousSibling = element,
        nth = 1;
      while (previousSibling = previousSibling.previousElementSibling) {
        if (previousSibling.nodeName.toLowerCase() == selector)
          nth++;
      }
      if (nth != 1)
        selector += ":nth-of-type(" + nth + ")";
    }
    path.unshift(selector);
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return path.join(" > ");
}
```

Whenever I arrive to the form element, the `element.parentNode` returns null. At his point the path is the following: ["form", "div", "div", "span", "span"]
Looking at the DOM the element has a parent:

[image]

But in case I check the source code from the Chrome, I get the following:

```HTML
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' https://ekr.zdassets.com https://w3schools.zendesk.com https://*.w3schools.com https://*.google-analytics.com https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com https://*.g.doubleclick.net https://*.google.com https://authapi.w3sdevelop.com https://authapi.w3stages.com https://authapi.w3spaces.com https://2k205wtqq3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com https://aydmoags80.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com https://tryit-api.w3schools.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://static.zdassets.com/ https://www.googletagmanager.com/ https://www.google-analytics.com/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/ https://www.gstatic.com/; img-src 'self' https:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com; font-src https://fonts.gstatic.com; base-uri 'self'; frame-src https://www.google.com/; ">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
  <meta name="description" content="Profile pages">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png">
  <title>W3Schools</title>
  <script async="" nonce="f79c2bd4-92db-47cb-a921-fb3dd82e0188" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-3855518-1"/>
  <script id="ze-snippet" src="https://static.zdassets.com/ekr/snippet.js?key=41c2038e-584a-4eb0-b6fe-696d291af18b"/>
  <script src="datalayer.js"/>
  <link href="static/css/2.af63c107.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="static/css/main.b5d8544f.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <body>
    <noscript>W3Schools Online Web Tutorials</noscript>
    <div id="root"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.zESettings={webWidget:{contactForm:{attachments:!0},color:{launcherText:"#FFFFFF"}}},zE("webWidget","setLocale","en")</script>
    <script src="static/js/runtime-main.f3c6b2f6.js"/>
    <script src="static/js/2.32a96327.chunk.js"/>
    <script src="static/js/main.b4c4cd86.chunk.js"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

It looks like there is some problem with the HTML tags, but the page renders correctly and in dev tools under the elements tab I can see everything correctly.

I tried to look for the answer here on Stackowerflow, but I have not found anything. What can be the problem?

Comment: It's not my HTML, but anyway checking the URL with the suggested tool only returns a warning: The type attribute is unnecessary for JavaScript resources.

Comment: What is the value of `path` when element.parentNode is null?

Comment: ["form", "div", "div", "span", "span"]

Comment: I have read the "How to ask" and I am fulfilling all points of it. In case you do not want to help, why do you comment here? The HTML has no problem proven by the tool suggested by you.

Comment: It seems you're running your code inside some W3School wrapper? Since you posted a HTML page with only W3 scripts? This way we cannot reproduce your error. I would suggest building the W3 example on your local machine.

Comment: @Kokodoko It is not in a W3School wrapper, it is the Sign up page of W3School: https://profile.w3schools.com/signup
I am developing a Chrome Extension which automatically generates different selectors, and I want to make it as stable as I can and during testing it I found the above mention site, where I experienced this strange behavior: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenideium-element-inspe/mgfhljklijclnfeglclagdeoiknnmnda